# What's Julia's equivalent of R's seq(..., length.out = n)

Tags: r, julia

I can see from this link that R's equivalent of seq is n:m in (http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2012/04/09/comparing-julia-and-rs-vocabularies/).

But the case of `seq(a,b, length.out = n)` is not covered.

For example `seq(1, 6, length.out=3)` gives `c(1.0, 3.5, 6.0)`. It is a really nice way to specify the number of outputs.

What's its equivalent in Julia?

Comment: Are you sure the 'seq(1, 5, length.out=3)' will give the output of (1.0, 3.5, 6.0) in R !!?  or I am missing something?

Comment: Apologies. Typo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**As of Julia 1.0:**

`linspace` has been deprecated. You can still use `range`:

```
julia> range(0, stop = 5, length = 3)
0.0:2.5:5.0
```

As @TasosPapastylianou noted, if you want this to be a vector of values, you can use `collect`:

```
julia> collect( range(0, stop = 5, length = 3) )
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
0.0
2.5
5.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `linspace` function. Note this is synonymous to the equivalent function in matlab / octave.

Also note that this returns a "steprange" type object:

```julia
julia> a = linspace(1,5,9)
1.0:0.5:5.0

julia> typeof(a)
StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}

julia> collect(a)
9-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 1.5
 2.0
 2.5
 3.0
 3.5
 4.0
 4.5
 5.0
```

---

PS: similarly, there exists a `range` function which is equivalent to the `start:step:stop` syntax, similar to the `seq(from=, to=, by=)` syntax in R.